# QML ListView `highlightFollowsCurrentItem` auto scroll interrupted by mouse hover

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

When using ListView in QML, the property `highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true` sets the behaviour of the view to automatically scroll to the currently highlighted item, if it is out of view.

The problem I'm having is that if the mouse is hovering over the list view, it highlights any item that is passed under it, which interrupts the automatic navigation to the highlighted object. For the scroll to complete, the user must make sure the mouse is not over the ListView content.

I've tried binding `interactive: !moving` such that the View will not accept mouse events while it is moving, but this results in a binding loop error.

Comment: can you share the source code ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].